# Android Anim Folder

Tags: android, animation

In my Android SDK folder on Windows I have found anim folder with lot of different .xml files, but in my application in eclipse when I try to load one it only shows me few of them. How can I access those rest without creating custom XML file and pasting the code into it? I mean can I access them like R.anim.file.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is an `R.class` file precompiled and given for you by the Android SDK. You can simply refer to it by `android.R.anim.slid_in`, `android.R.anim.slide_out` etc.

Find more out about it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.anim.html